# VB.net - How do you have your installer run other setup (.exe) files?

Tags: vb.net

I have multiple setup exes (7 to be exact) that I'd like to group into one easy to install package.

How do you setup the main installer to run those setup exe files automatically?

Comment: are they all projects in your solution?  could they be?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well the name of the program you can use is InnoSetup. Look for it and try it out